# Is flexible gas pipe safe to use for main or long runs?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, gas, natural-gas

The house we purchased is a "tear-down". A builder bought the older structure, partially tore it down and built a bigger house on the old footprint.  A lot of the original gas piping is still in the basement.  However, for all of the new runs, they used that yellow flexible gas piping.  This includes the main run up to the furnace in the attic, as the house is 2-zone heat & ac.

Articles like [this one](http://www.sfgate.com/opinion/openforum/article/Bending-the-truth-about-flexible-gas-pipes-2821672.php) get me a bit concerned.  In your experience, how safe & resilient is flexible gas tubing?  What if anything do I need to be concerned about?  How do I protect myself and family if the integrity of any of this gas tubing were to be compromised?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the tubing, and/or any writing on the tubing?

Comment: When I built my new home , ALL the gas lines were Steel and only used flexible gas line at the termination points between the Steel pipe and the individual appliances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two types of tubing most people think of, when you say "flexible gas tubing".  The first and more common, are flexible gas connectors.

[image: Gas Connectors]

These guys are typically 3-6' long, and are used to connect appliances to the gas piping. They are only to be used as a short link between the fixed piping and the appliance, and so are considered a "*connector*" and not true piping.

The other product; that may not be as well known, is [Corrugated Stainless Steel Tubing (CSST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrugated_stainless_steel_tubing).

[image: CSST]

This stuff is made up of semi-rigid corrugated stainless steel tubing surrounded by a polyethylene jacketing, and is designed and approved to be used as a gas piping method.  There may be problems caused by lightning strikes, but the solution is to simply have an Electrician install a bonding device.

The author of the linked article seems to be unaware of the differences between these two types of tubing, and is simply spreading misinformation.  While it's true that you wouldn't want to plumb your house using only flexible gas connectors, this is **not** what's being proposed.

If you smell gas, evacuate the building and call 911 (emergency services).

Comment: This stuff that i'm talking about is indeed the CSST as shown in your picture.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago we had a gas stove moved to the opposite side of the room.

The plumber used CSST, and not simply as an extension to the old line.  Instead he laid a whole new CSST line right back to where the original line fed from the main pipe that also feeds the furnace and water heater.  The system *is* electrically grounded.

This method was a lot cheaper and easier than using black pipe, and avoided having to rip down much of the ceiling in the floor below.

The work was done by a large reputable company that's been in business for many decades.

Answer (score 0):

CSST is safe to run from your main to very gas appliance you have. I have seen and helped install this in new home builds, and redone gas lines.

Now the connectors I've installed or only to be used at a maximum (in my area) of only 6ft.

I'm in no way saying its safe to do either yourself unless you've had experience with gas piping.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, however, I'm not sure this adds a whole lot to the existing answers. If you can add a new angle that wasn't considered in the previous answers that would help a lot. While you're thinking about it, take the [tour] and browse the [help], especially the section on answering, to familiarize yourself with how this Q&A site is different from general discussion forums.